# Getting Stuart Sierra's component and lein-ring to play nicely without a global system-map

Tags: clojure, global-variables, reload, compojure, ring

I've been using `lein-ring` for some time now and in particular the auto-reload facility which I find very helpful.

Whilst I like the reloaded workflow in cider - based on a variation of Stuart Sierra's user.clj - I also have a use-case where there's a bunch of micro-services starting in a Docker composition with `command: lein ring server-headless`.

This has been working tremendously well over the past couple of months for me, prior to seeking a dependency-injection solution to improve my tests/mocking.

With host volume mounts to the various projects, when I change the code for any service in the composition, `lein-ring` takes care of reloading, allowing me to execute integration-level and exploratory tests as I go (no restarts really helps with momentum).

However, I'm just getting started with `component`, and have reached an impasse where I cannot see a way of getting the reloading benefits of `lein-ring` without introducing a global system map.

I've created a minimal re-production of where I have got to and was hoping someone could advise on whether what I'm aiming for is possible.

https://github.com/codeasone/component-reload-issue

**Question:** Is there a way for me to achieve the reloading behaviour I want with `lein-ring`, whilst also maintaining the encapsulation and testing advantages that `component` brings *without* introducing a global `system-map` and adandoning the componentisation and DI for `demo-routes`?

Comment: For this use-case, I'm presently having a better experience with `mount`. It appears to coexist happily with `lein-ring` functionality and give me the separation-of-concerns, dependency injection, and ability to swap in stubs https://github.com/tolitius/mount#swapping-alternate-implementations that I'm looking for.